# Automated testing of cipher security for import/export compliance

Tags: encryption

What do we know about systems that automatically test and grade cipher security. The application in mind would be for checking for compliance with import/export regulations.

I imagine a system that automatically tests for known plaintext, chosen plaintext and the like, presumably by some kind of cryptanalysis operating on the cipher as a black box function, or subroutines of it.

The OpenSSL export ciphers are "exportable with respect to old US crypto regulations". I want to consider other countries import/export policies.

This question supposes that import and export compliance is still a real concern in the industry, despite many articles claiming otherwise.

Comment: What do you mean, to test if they are secure as in crypto-analysis, or how much security they are *supposed* to have?

Comment: To test if they meet security requirements, as described by whatever export rules are in place.

Comment: If they exist I doubt that they will be full proof, especially if they don't rely on the source code. In principle a security algorithm consists of a almost random sequence of logical operators. It would as good as impossible to detect them. Library calls, on the other hand, should be relatively easy to distinguish. PS I'm pretty sure this has already been asked somewhere, but I cannot find a reference.

Comment: Updated the question to emphasise that this is not about analysis of the code, but of the security properties of the cipher. I imagine that such a system would be able to grade the strength of the cipher, where depending on this strength the cipher is deemed to be exportable or not exportable.

Comment: Nowadays **import** restrictions are arguably more of an issue, especially for repressive governments.

Comment: Very interesting. Rephrased the question to include **import** restrictions.

Comment: Is your question something like this "given a set of formally specified regulations derived from law, can we verify that cryptographic cipher X (given it's mathematical representation or it's source code, or whatever, you should specify this), meets these regulations?"

Comment: Yes, correct. Is that a reasonable question?

Answer (score 1):

No.  There is no known automated method to determine whether some cipher is secure or not.  So, given some new cipher you've never heard of there's no automated way to test whether it meets your particular security requirements.

Instead, normally you would rely upon a cryptographer expert (e.g., a consultant or in-house expert) or upon standards or best practices to select a cipher that is widely believed to meet your security requirements -- then you implement the cipher, and use test vectors and other methods to test whether you have correctly implemented that cipher.  For instance, you might use one of the export-strength ciphersuites in SSL.

This answer is not intended to advise you on the export regulations of any country.  If you need to know what they are, consult a lawyer.

Comment: The OpenSSL export ciphers are "exportable with respect to old US crypto regulations". I want to consider other countries export policies. Do you believe that export regulations are no longer a concern?

Comment: @TruthSerum, you didn't state that in the question.  Please edit your question, and this time make sure all relevant information is included in the question.  Actually, I'm finding it difficult to guess exactly what you are asking or looking for.  This is starting to look like a "chameleon question" (one that changes each time someone adds an answer); that's discouraged on this site and may discourage people from answering.

Comment: I updated the question with the new information. I hope the question does not need to be edited anymore.

Comment: @TruthSerum, I still don't get it.  In what sense does my answer not answer your question?  Everything I wrote still applies.  No, there is no known way to automatically test and grade the security of an arbitrary cipher.  That's not how we do it in practice.  Perhaps if you elaborate the question it will become clearer what you are looking for and/or why you think this doesn't answer the question?

Comment: It's a valid answer - upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of export regulations requiring that encryption algorithms should (or shouldn't) satisfy certain security properties, such as CPA/CCA security.

Export regulations are more related to other issues, such as the ability of certain organizations to inspect the code (e.g., the Bureau of Industry and Security and the NSA, in the US) and the size of the keys. For example, see the following excerpt from the ["Encryption Export Controls"](http://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/forms-documents/doc_view/334-encryption-export-controls-75-fed-reg-36-482-june-25-2010) US regulation (emphasis added):

> You must submit a classification request or encryption registration to
>   BIS for mass market encryption commodities and software eligible for
>   the Cryptography Note employing **a key length greater than 64 bits for
>   the symmetric algorithm** (**or, for commodities and software not
>   implementing any symmetric algorithms, employing a key length greater
>   than 768 bits for asymmetric algorithms or greater than 128 bits for
>   elliptic curve algorithms**) in accordance with the requirements of §
>   742.15(b) of the EAR in order to be released from the ‘‘EI’’ and ‘‘NS’’ controls of ECCN 5A002 or 5D002

**Update**: In other words, from the point of view of compliance to export/import regulations, it may be **completely irrelevant** if the encryption system is insecure under known plaintext attacks, CPA/CCA attacks, etc. If you look into the US regulations on the matter, there is no reference to that kind of security properties; as noted above, the most important things are key length and the possibility of inspecting the code. Note however, that these regulations may change at any moment, and that they are different (sometimes just slightly) for every country. That is, they completely depend on each specific country and for each specific moment in time. As D.W. noted in the other answer, you better call a lawyer, than relying on a piece of software.

Knowing this, the verification of some of these requirements could be automated. For example, for the US case, it would be relatively easy to develop a software that inspects the code of the target system and check that it is using allowed key sizes. However, there are some other requirements, such as publication of the source code or notification to relevant parties, which are inherently bureaucratic procedures, and whose validation may be difficult to automate.